# Software RAID 1 resync's on SATA cable switch?

Tags: raid, sata, raid-1, mdadm

I made a mistake when I opened up my desktop removed a 2 disk RAID 1 and reconnected them, but with the SATA cables switched, such that `sda` became `sdb` and viceversa.

On boot, the RAID array started to resync everything from scratch to the other disk. These are 2TB disks and a clean resync takes ~3hrs.

My question is;

- Why did it behave like that, is that normal?
- How can I prevent auto-re-syncing from scratch without manual intervention so that I can have a chance to analyze what is wrong?